# In Visual Studio, how do you find other projects referencing a single project in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

In a Visual Studio 2015 solution, is there a simple way to find out which projects are referencing (referring to?) a certain project?

I've got a solution with a 105 projects (yes...that's a bad idea and we're working on it). It's common for some of these projects to refer to others. Short of temporarily deleting the project and rebuilding to check for errors, is there another way to check for projects in the solution referring to the project in question?

I've got resharper which has a tool (Project dependency diagram) to find the projects reference by a certain project which is the opposite of what I require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ReSharper, right click on a project in Solution Explorer and select "Find Code Dependent on Module". This will find all usages of code in the selected project. You can group this by project, and that will show you the projects that are referencing your selected project (and it will show you how they are referencing it, too).

Answer (score 1):

This information is contained in the csproj or vcxproj, not the solution. You should be able to readily search all the csprojs with this:

```
grep --include=*.csproj -Elr "ProjectReference.*?PROJECTNAME" .
```

and google for `gnuwin32 grep` if you dont have grep handy, or do something similar with a windows tool (`filelocator pro` is what I use).

If you for some reason need to restrict the search to the projects listed in a solution while excluding other adjacent projects, I think you're going to end up with a much more complex command or a script. In many cases I would expect you can just use your wits to ignore resulting .csproj that arent relevant.